# Scroll Bar in UI part of IOS app development

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, cordova

How can I give scroll-bar in my index.html such that the header and footer divs remain fixed on the screen, while the content part which lies between header and footer can be scrolled if the content exceeds the available space.

Does anybody have any idea?

thanks in advance.

Comment: ok, I re-tagged your question

Answer (score 0):

You can try iScroll

http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

it's the best option I have find to keep the fixed header and footer and scroll the content between them